# gm conversion issue in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am converting an image from jpg to png, but it is giving the error. Below is the code and error.

```
gm('E:/image1.jpg').write('E:/image2.png', function(err){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{console.log('image converted.')}
    })
```

The error is:

```
[Error: Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: gm "convert" "E:/image1.jpg" "E:/image2.png" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found]
```

Do I have to npm graphicsmagick and imagemagick?

Answer (score 23):

Probably graphicsmagick / imagemagick is not installed correctly, [download GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/download.html) or [download ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php), if your are using Ubuntu, these commands are useful.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dhor/myway
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: I got an error because I thought graphicsmagic will automatically download imagemagick also, but it's not. After seen your answer I installed imagemagick and issue solved, you rock buddy.

Comment: You sir, are a genius, almost pulled all the hair in my afro coz of that error

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem on windows! Maybe my answer will help someone!

If you use `gm` on windows you should download windows binaries [here](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/download.html) and add `gm.exe` to your windows environment `PATH` variable. After that you have to restart your PC.
Then install corresponding node package with `npm install gm` and it will work! ;)

Comment: Finally found the right answer ! thank you so much !

Answer (score 8):

Try `brew install graphicsmagick`. Does that resolve the error you saw?

Comment: I have tried installing graphicsmagick and its path to the enviroment variable is also set while installing. but still not working.

Answer (score 5):

I have got it resolved by installing graphicsmagick and imagemagick and its path in environment variable will be automatically set out. Then I have to restart the windows to reflect the changes and now I can successfully converts and image.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with below command and it will solve your problem

- sudo apt install graphicsmagick

Answer (score 0):

When installing ImageMagick from https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php, be sure to check the option to "Install legacy utilities (convert)".

Answer (score 0):

#### Opensuse

If you are developing on **OpenSuse** OS this issue can arise as well. To solve, you need to install the **ImageMagick** and **GraphicsMagick** packages:

```
sudo zypper install ImageMagick GraphicsMagick
```

Answer (score 0):

There few steps to solve this error.

1. Confirm the GraphicsMagick is installed in your user in the terminal.
2. $ gm
3. $ sudo gm //[Command Line Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znmA3.png)
4. Both "gm" and "sudo gm" commands should return the most of the time server running in the sudo user and we might have installed this in normal user so that Sudo user don't know the about installed package configure in the normal user. In short, make sure code running in sudo user then same mode GraphicsMagick should be available.

If did not got the above and got something like "command not found in the terminal"
then use this link.
https://www.tecmint.com/graphicsmagick-image-processing-cli-tool-for-linux/

also check the this link contains only command package might not available to download so https://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/graphicsmagick/
change the version in the download link of the wget and follow the steps in above link.

Answer (score 0):

GraphicsMagick Windows Installation

step 1:

```
choco install graphicsmagick
```

Follow this [doc](https://chocolatey.org/install) to install Chocolatey on windows :)

step 2:

go to graphicsmagick installation location.

> Ex: C:\Program Files\GraphicsMagick-1.3.36-Q8

step 3:

add gm.exe location to your windows environment PATH variable

> Ex: C:\Program Files\GraphicsMagick-1.3.36-Q8

setp 4:

open a new terminal (command prompt/ powershell)

run `gm.exe`

if you get 'gm.exe unable to start correctly' error, install the VS2008 package from this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2008-vc-90-sp1-no-longer-supported)

step 5:

test the installation

Select "Command Prompt" from the Windows Start menu. Within the window type

```
gm convert logo: logo.miff

gm convert logo.miff win:
```

and the GraphicsMagick logo should be displayed in a window.